# Singleton, Application Scope and Timers across a Clustered Environment

Tags: timer, singleton, wildfly, high-availability, wildfly-10

I have setup a clustered environment on Amazon Web Service using Wildfly 10 with infinispan s3ping. Everything works fine. But singletons, application scope objects, and timers works on each node separately.

I have to make these work across the full cluster instead of a single node.

What is the best way to accomplish this. Can you give me a starting point or a good tutorial if possible?